# Make exe file from cbp in Codeblocks

Tags: c, csv

I have  made a program in code blocks in C language.This program takes its input from CSV file and then prints on screen.
Now,I want to convert it into "exe" file.So when i try to run the application from bin  folder,it can't open the csv file.
How to make exe file in this case?[image]

Comment: There is exe in your `bin` folder already.

Comment: Yes.But that is not working.I think its because my code try to open the csv file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you add information. Your main question about how to make an EXE is solved. You have another problem, please consider to edit title and prose of your question. You can do this as long as no answer is posted, I think. -- Please show us how you use the EXE, the result you get, and what you expect instead. Oh, and please post these as text, not as screenshots! -- You do have some error checks in your program, like checking the return value of `fopen()` or what else you use, don't you?